# What would be the motivation for a recruiter showing up at your on-site interview?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

My first time working with a recruiter. I have a second, in person, interview coming for an advanced programming job and the recruiter said he'll meet me in the lobby. Seems strange to me that he wants to be there.

In your experience what is the motivation for a recruiter showing up on-site just prior to the interview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had one recruiter doing this (of the maybe 10 interviews I'd had through a recruiter).  I thought it was weird, because my connection in the recruiting company was his colleague, not him (although it was him who is the contact person of this company I'm interviewing at... )

So he showed up.  I've never even met him before.  He didn't even say he'd show up.  10 minutes before the interview, he called me and said he'd meet me at the elevator of the building I'm having an interview at.  I was thinking... uh, OK...

But then when my interviewer walked out and greeted me, I realize why he was doing it.  He has a very strong connection with the hiring managers, and he's probably trying to allure to the hiring manager that I'm a strong candidate.  And even if the company didn't think I am, it still shows the company that he's responsible and personally screen and follow up to every candidate.

Comment: This is dead on. After meeting with my recruiter off-site and getting to know how he operated it was clear that his small two man company won exclusive rights to search for clients for the particular company I was interviewing for. He had just as much vested interest in ensuring the introductions went smoothly and had just as much to lose if I did not succeed.

Answer (score 7):

I've had a few recruiters do this.  I think it's a little weird, but I can see why they'd do it.

They're evaluating you to see who they're putting in front of their customers.  They want to see you looking professional, being well-prepared, sober (Yes, it happens), etc.  Also, they want to share any last-minute info they've gathered.

They're putting their name right under yours, so they have an interest in you presenting well.

Comment: Bit late for that, isn't it? All the good recruiters I've worked with wanted to meet me before sending me to a potential employer for the first time, but by the time you're in the employer's lobby, I'm not sure what they can really do if you _are_ drunk, crazed, etc.

Comment: OP makes a interesting point, i can however see a different reason recruiter will want to come to the interview: they are probably the better negotiators. They might be able to pump up your salary to obtain more benefits.

Comment: Meeting days before is good, but meeting right before is needed to know exactly how you presented yourself on that day.  It will give them more info that they may track to help determine future advice for future candidates.  Also, they may think they can put you more at ease which can help during the interview (they thinking it doesn't make it true, but it explains why they might do it).

Comment: @Carson63000 - I am assuming that all the preliminaries went off well, too.  However, seeing how you "show up" is something they're interested in, as well.  I never really thought about what they could do if you showed up unprepared, other than not put you in front of anyone else again.